# Communication between services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I have approximately 51 micro-services made in **Spring Boot**, so I'm having to communicate them between *Rest Template*, and I'm having a poor performance, and not all micro-services need to have endpoints. I'm thinking of using *Spring Eureka*, but I do not know if it's the solution, so I see it uses RestTemplate underneath the cloths (I may be wrong).
My micro-services are in the google cloud.

Comment: I have tried to implement a solution for similar problem https://github.com/StanislavLapitsky/SpringSOAProxy The result is you can join some of the services in one endpoint in call them internally. But still it's RestTemplate based

Comment: @StanislavL 
I'm going to take a look, I've been thinking about working with queues in Rabbit for these calls, but I'm not sure it's the best solution either.

Comment: How Rabbit could improve the performance? It could be done async mode but requires the same time anyway. Of course if you have kind of a pipeline where each call is synchronous it require  long time to call multiple services. It's fine if you break this into multiple independent steps and each one is fast. Could you point real bottleneck?

Comment: @StanislavL In fact, so it was just an idea, I'm going to start testing eureka, today I use nginx to do the services discovery and what this is about loading the calls, I wonder if there would be any tool like buses, esb, where I could expose These services